# How to run EMR steps first sequentially and then in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-emr, java.util.concurrent

[image]

This process can be achieved easily with the help of orchestration engine like Step Function but for some reason we cannot use. Here, I want to understand can we do some kind of code manipulation to run parallel execution after step2 where step 3 and step4 will run in parallel and after step 4 it will run step 5 in sequence.

Any reference how can I achieve this or anyone does so far?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-now-allows-you-to-run-multiple-steps-in-parallel-cancel-running-steps-and-integrate-with-aws-step-functions/

Comment: Can't go with Step Function for some reason. Looking any other way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can't go with Step Function for some reason, you can try Oozie.

[Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/) is a workflow scheduler system to manage Apache Hadoop jobs. Its also a EMR managed service, one click to install. Oozie jobs are Directed Acyclical Graphs (DAGs).